# Best practice to serve static files on Tomcat integrated with Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, web, tomcat9

If using Tomcat integrated with Apache (web server), how should I setup to make Apache serve all static files (html, png, css, ...) in my war file deployed in `webapps`? Use a symbolic link? I would like to do nothing after re-deploy my war including updated static files file if possible.

For example, if all elements of my application in `webapps` are:

- my-app/app.jsp => Should be returned by Tomcat
- my-app/html/index.html => Should be returned by Apache
- my-app/images/log.png => Should be returned by Apache
- my-app/css/app.css => Should be returned by Apache

Answer (score 0):

See Red hat [solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/67298):

> Create images in the /var/www/img directory
>   In httpd.conf, have the following configuration.
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>  ServerName myapp.example.com
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/
>  Alias /images "/var/www/img/"  
>   <Directory "/var/www/img">  
>    Options +Indexes  
>    AllowOverride None  
>    Order allow,deny  
>    Allow from all  
>   </Directory>
>  </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> Go to url http://localhost/images and you should see the images listed.To prevent directory listings remove Options +Indexes.

Another option in [Tomcat](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/)

> Tomcat’s `server.xml` configuration file
>
> ```
> <Host appBase="webapps"
>        autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
>        xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
> ...
> <Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/static" />
> </Host>
> ```
>
> A `<Context>` element is added inside the `<Host>` element. Context has two attributes: `docBase` is the directory on disk that contains your static files and `path` is the URL that you want to serve the files on.

Comment: Does it mean my-app/html, images and css should be moved to /var/www/img every after re-deployed?

Comment: @blackeyedcenter it's a solution to use apache server (without tomcat) for static files

Comment: @blackeyedcenter added a tomcat option

Comment: If possible, I want to only re-deploy my war file and don't want to move static files in the war. Can your solution do it?